# Variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have seen a lot of links introducing the variadic templates. But I have never seen any compilable example that demonstrates this approach.

Could someone provide me with some links in which such compilable examples can be found?

Comment: What do you mean by "compilable example"? I think all those links introduced examples which can be compiled.

Comment: no, that is not the case. This examples describe only the deceleration of such veriadic temlates may be the definition too, but never the call, in case of variadic function, or instantiate some variadic classes in the main function. I need actually just simple example which I can copy and compile it to better understand the variadic mechanism..

Comment: Are you sure you're using a compiler that supports it and invoke it with the correct options?

Comment: Actually, I just meant that I need some examples to compile it. I do know that the compile flag -std=c++0x should be set. However all example I found are printf like. I need a small but meaningful example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic templates are part of the C++0x standard which is not yet officially released. They are supported by gcc since version 4.3, but you need to enable support for C++0x by adding the compiler switch -std=c++0x.

Comment: Right. And as far as I know, the Microsoft Compiler doesn't yet support variadic templates. Just saying.

Comment: They announced some features that will be in MSVC11 (in 2012), and Variadic Templates was not on that list.  Time for me to learn to install MinGW.

Comment: @Virus721 he was complaining that there is no compilable example. There are tons of examples - the only reason they don't compile are: missing compiler support or missing compiler switch

Answer (score 28):

One of the simplest possible examples is the following implementation of `max` which isn't even templated on types.

```
int maximum(int n)
{
    return n;
}

template<typename... Args>
int maximum(int n, Args... args)
{
    return max(n, maximum(args...));
}
```

Only slightly more complex is the canonical `printf` implementation:

```
void printf(const char *s)
{
  while (*s)
  {
    if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%')
      throw "invalid format string: missing arguments";
    std::cout << *s++;
  }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printf(const char* s, T value, Args... args)
{
  while (*s)
  {
    if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%')
    {
      std::cout << value;
      printf(s, args...); // call even when *s == 0 to detect extra arguments
      return;
    }
    std::cout << *s++;
  }
  throw "extra arguments provided to printf";
}
```

Comment: Are the `...` after `Args` and `args` just syntactic salt, or are there also ways in which variadic parameters can be used without the `...`?

Comment: The placement of `...` matters. Consider two variadic template functions `sum` and `product`. Now call them from within another variadic template with parameters `2,3,4` the value of `product(sum(args...))` will be 9 and the value of `product(sum(args)...)` will be 24.

Comment: @Stewart I expanded on this theme slightly in [a blog post](http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/did-you-pack-that-yourself/)

Comment: does the line `printf(s, args...);` mean a recursive runtime call to another function compiled with 1 less argument or does the compiler recursively expand this line to body of printf with 1 less argument?

Comment: @youda008 it's not technically recursion, the compiler instanciates a new overload  of `printf` with one less parameter and adds a call to this function. This function call may, or may not, be inlined but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

Variadic templates are a C++0x feature that primarily targets authors of generic libraries. I would not expect to see them in "user code". For example, in the C++0x standard library they are used in a lot of places: std::function, std::async, std::reference_wrapper, std::tuple, std::packaged_task, ...

To give you an example I'll show you how a reference_wrapper might be implemented with respect to variadic templates:

```
template<class T>
class reference_wrapper
{
    T *ptr;
public:
    explicit reference_wrapper(T& thing) : ptr(&thing) {}
    explicit reference_wrapper(T&&     ) = delete;

    operator T&() const {return *ptr;}

    template<class... Args>
    decltype( declval<T&>()(declval<Args>()...) )
    operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return (*ptr)(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

This is not perfectly conforming to the standard draft but it is supposed to be compilable with little modification. It demonstrates multiple C++0x features:

- deleted functions (disabling the constructor for rvalues)
- rvalue references (detecting rvalue arguments to the constructor, perfect forwarding)
- type deduction via `decltype`
- standard library function template `declval` to create objects for the purpose of building an expression for `decltype` (GCC does not yet offer this function template. You have to write it yourself)
- variadic templates (accepting an arbitrary number of parameters)

The purpose of the variadic member template is to forward arguments to the object referred to by `ptr`. This should work in case T is a function pointer type or a class type with overloaded function call operator.

cheers!
s

Answer (score 6):

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates) is good starting point.
- [Gregor, Douglas; Jaakko Järvi; Gary Powell (9 September 2006). "Variadic Templates (Revision 3)".](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2080.pdf)

Comment: yes, I looked at it. I tried to create an example to to compile it without success. I need an compilable example which, as I said, demonstrates this approach by running it

Answer (score 6):

A very simple example of variadic template:

Suppose we want to have a function which takes variable number of arguments and prints them all. For ex:

```
print("Hello", 1, 3.14, 5L);
```

For that functionality to work, we would basically require two functions:

**First one, a function which takes variable number of arguments:**

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T t, Args ...args){
     std::cout << t << ", ";
     print(args...);
}
```

Some explanation:

1.) Parameter Packs denoted by ellipsis(...), that appear in parameter list.

```
typename...Args 
        |  | << Optional whitespace. Can have multiple whitespaces in between them
    Args...args
```

That means, these all are same.

```
typename ...args
typename...args
typename   ...   args
```

So, you don't have to worry about the correct position of the whitespace in there. Though, IMO at most one whitespace should be used as a best practice.

2.) Pack Expansion: A pattern followed by an ellipsis.

```
print(args...); //expand when you wish to use them
```

3.) Parameter pack accepts *zero or more* template args. So, `print(T t, Args... args)` accepts *one or more* args.

---

Once you understand that, we can visualize the call flow as below:

```
print("Hello", 1, 3.14, 5L);
```

translates into:

```
print(string, int, float, long);
```

which calls

```
print(int, float, long);
```

which calls

```
print(float, long);  // say Level 2
```

which calls

```
print(long);         // say Level 1
```

which calls

```
print();             // say Level 0
```

If you have followed the Point#3 carefully, you must have realized that `print(T t, Args... args)` can't handle call at Level 0.
So we need another function here with same name to catch up at any level >=0.

---

**Second one, a function to *grab* the call at the top of call stack**:

Catch at level 0:

```
void print(){}
```

or, Catch at level 1:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T t){ std::cout << t;}
```

or, Catch at level 2:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void print(T t, U u){ std::cout << t << ", " << u;}
```

so on...

Any of these would work. Hope this helps you next time you go about writing such function or class.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and easy-to-follow answer. I can't believe I found something like this all the way at the bottom of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of variadic templates that I put up on my blog:
http://thenewcpp.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/variadic-templates-part-1-2/

It compiles. It demonstrates finding the largest type from a group of types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
struct find_biggest;

//the biggest of one thing is that one thing
template <typename First>
struct find_biggest<First>
{
  typedef First type;
};

//the biggest of everything in Args and First
template <typename First, typename... Args>
struct find_biggest<First, Args...>
{
  typedef typename find_biggest<Args...>::type next;
  typedef typename std::conditional
  <
    sizeof(First) >= sizeof(next),
    First,
    next
  >::type type;
};
```

Comment: Mmmmm i've always thought that C++ was made for a more human readable syntax than C...

Comment: Maybe in some cases. But you can't even do this in C, so it's not really comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Before C++11, you can create template only with the fixed count of parameters.

Firts template for the function with one parameter.

Second template for the function  with two parameters.
... i.e.

Since C++11 you can write only one template, compiler will generate required function itself.

Good example
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

another syntax: expanding, e.g.

```
template<typename VAL, typename... KEYS>
class MyMaps
{
  typedef std::tuple< std::map<KEYS,VAL>... > Maps;
}
```

hence:

```
MyMaps<int,int,string>:Maps
```

is now actually:

```
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,std::map<string,int> >
```