# How to propagate an undefined number of template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, multiple-arguments

Using the following class, I would like to be able to create an instance of a specified `Foo()` to store and call a function, but how can I transmit the necessary arguments to a function `call` ?

```
template<class R, class... Args> struct Foo {
    std::function<R(Args...)> func;

    Foo(const std::function<R(Args...)> &funcIn) : func(funcIn) {}

    R call(Args...) {
        return func(/* ? */);
    }
};
```

E.g:

```
int main() {
    typedef typename Foo<int(int)> Bar;
    Bar x([](int y, int z){return y + z + 2;});
    std::cout << x.call(12, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To make it [short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634379/variadic-templates)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just add name of arguments.

```
R call(Args... args) {
    return func(args...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple

```
R call (Args... as) {
    return func(as...);
}
```

This should work well if the `Args...` types are `int`, `long`, `float` and other simple types without support for move syntax.

If you want add perfect forwarding, something as

```
template <typename ... As>
R call (As && ... as) {
    return func(std::forward<As>(as)...);
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

If I understand correctly (?) according Smit Ycyken this code doesn't even compile.

There are some errors in the OP original code (the `class Foo` should be a `struct` or make something `public`; the `typedef` in `main()` is wrong) but the following corrected code compile with my g++ and my clang++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class R, class... Args> struct Foo {
    std::function<R(Args...)> func;

    Foo(const std::function<R(Args...)> &funcIn) : func(funcIn) {}

    R call (Args... as) {
       return func(as...);
    }
};

int main ()
 {
   typedef Foo<int, int, int> Bar;
   Bar x([](int y, int z){return y + z + 2;});
   std::cout << x.call(12, 7);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Same here. To make it wrong without template header. Give somebody this bald head a hat! `R call (Args... as) {...}`

Comment: @SmitYcyken - the first example, the second one or both?

Comment: @SmitYcyken - answer modified; please, can you explain what's wrong with my answer?