# How does std::make_shared and std::make_unique work behind the scenes?

Tags: c++

Edit: I am referring to std::make_shared and std::make_shared, not their actual constructors. I have edited the title but the text below still talks about constructors. Ignore that I use the word "constructor"

I am trying to learn how smart pointers work behind the scenes but the source files seem to go beyond my understanding, so I figured maybe someone here could help me. How does the declaration and implementation of smart pointers' constructors work?

Normally, you create constructors like this:

```
Object(SomeType member) : member_(member) {}
```

Smart pointers obviously use class templates to let the coder choose what type the pointer will be pointing to, but the constructor also takes the arguments needed to construct an object of the type the pointer will be pointing to. How is this achieved? How do you create a constructor like this, when we don't know how many or what types of arguments will be needed, since we don't know the type of the object we will be constructing?

```
Object(/*???*/) : member_(new SomeType(/*???*/)) {}
```

Comment: It's called *variadic templates*

Comment: `but the constructor` Smart pointers only take a pointer, objects are constructed outside of smart pointers. As for the sources, see ex. [std::make_unique from glibc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h#L961) - it's a call to `new` that is variadic, call to `std::unique_ptr`  takes the pointer.

Comment: I really recommend Arthur O'Dwyer's book "Mastering the C++17 STL", which discusses this in detail and gives a sample implementation that is easier to read than the default implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to forward an arbitrary amount of arguments to another constructor or function. For example:

```
#include <memory>  // Include std::forward.


template <typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    SmartPointer(Args&& ... args) : the_pointer{new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}} {}

    // Other methods ...

private:
    T* the_pointer;
};


struct Test
{
    int   a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<Test> pointer { 0, 1.0f };
}
```

This will forward the arguments `0` and `1.0f` to the constructor of `Test`. The expanded class would look something like this:

```
class SmartPointer
{
public:
    SmartPointer(int&& a, float&& b) 
        : the_pointer{new Test{std::forward<int&&>(a), std::forward<float&&>(b)}} {}

    // Other methods ...

private:
    Test* the_pointer;
};
```

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/6snEva)

Comment: upvoted, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: There is [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/1d7aec6c) to view template "expansion".

Answer (score 1):

This is a really robust feature of C++. It is called [Variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634379/variadic-templates).

Here is a simple example using

```
void print() 
{ 
}
template <typename T, typename... Types> 
void print(T var1, Types... var2) 
{ 
    cout << var1 << endl ; 
  
    print(var2...) ; 
}
```

Now you can call print with any number of variables of any type. On one condition though, that the type passed implements the operator `<<`.

Then, you can call print this way:

```
print(1, 2, 3.14, "Pass me any number of arguments", "I will print\n");
```

---

C++ standard library is incredibly generic. Understanding the library source code might be challenging if you lack an understanding of generic programming. A good practice exercise can be the following: Implement a sort function that sorts on one call many vectors containing different types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I try to run the code in your example, I get an error saying that there is no function for the call at the end of the print function. Why is this?

Comment: Oh of course, my bad. Let me add the function for the base case. Thank you for letting me know.