# How can I decrease the number of overloaded functions

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to know if there is an approach to decrease the number of overloaded function (function edit) in the below code.

```
 class foo
  {
  public:
      foo(int _a, char _b, float _c) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c){};
      void edit(int new_a);
      void edit(char new_b);
      void edit(float new_c);
      void edit(int new_a, char new_b);
      void edit(int new_a, float new_c);
      void edit(char new_b, float new_c);
      void edit(int new_a, char new_b, float new_c);
      void info();
  private:
     int   a;
     char  b;
     float c;
  };
```

Here is the implementation of the edit functions :

```
void foo::edit(int new_a)
{
    a = new_a;
}
void foo::edit(char new_b)
{
    b = new_b;
}
void foo::edit(float new_c)
{
    c = new_c;
}
void foo::edit(int new_a, char new_b)
{
    a = new_a;
    b = new_b;
}
void foo::edit(int new_a, float new_c)
{
    a = new_a;
    c = new_c;
}
void foo::edit(char new_b, float new_c)
{
    b = new_b;
    c = new_c;
}
void foo::edit(int new_a, char new_b, float new_c)
{
    a = new_a;
    b = new_b;
    c = new_c;
}
```

The edit function will let the user change the parameters of the object as he wishes.
But the thing is that if we add a new parameter we have to add to many overloaded function and I thought there should be a better way.

Here with 3 parameters we need 7 overloaded functions but if we had 4 parameters (a, b, c and  d) then we had to develop 14 overloaded function!
That's why I think there should be a better approach.

Thanks.

Comment: You can make it a  *member function template* but unless you show us the implementation of these `edit` member functions we can't say/advise anything with certainty.

Comment: Imagine that foo class  is a contacts manager and each object of this class contains parameters like (name, phone,email) and the edit function aims to change these parameters, but you might not want to change all parameters, maybe you need to change (phone and name) or just (phone) or just (name) so you have different options to change the parameters. You see what I mean?

Comment: let edit return a reference to `this` so you can chain them: `f.edit(1).edit(1.0);` then you do not need the combinatorial overloads. If setting more than one value needs a check that depends on both parameters then the same approach, but `edit` returns some proxy that does the checking

Comment: If I understand your comment-explanation of this code, any call to `edit()` with multiple parameters has the same effect as multiple calls to `edit()`, each with one parameter?  If that's correct, [edit] your question to better describe the problem you are solving.

Comment: void foo::edit(int new_a)
{
    a = new_a;
}

Comment: @meysamimani please [edit] your question to be complete.

Comment: void foo::edit(char new_b)
{
    b = new_b;
}

Comment: The two previous comments are implementation of the function, other overloaded functions follow the same task. That means, whatever the arguments are, the function will initialize the data member with the arguments of edit function.

Comment: Adding `private: template <typename T> void edit(T) = delete; template <typename T, typename U> void edit(T, U) = delete; template <typename T, typename U, typename V> void edit(T, U, V) = delete;` can help *disallow* other types from implicit conversion.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding implementation of the edit functions.

Comment: why do you think you need that combinatoric explosion? Why the caller cannot call `edit(1)` and then `edit(1.0f)` instead of `edit(1,1.0f)` ? If you add one member you need to add one setter, its not clear why you want all combinations

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen this. There is a particularly elegant approach using variadic templates and `constexpr if`. Hint: solve the single argument template version first, then move onto the variadic case (2 and 3 arguments). The Boost developers (www.boost.org) are good at this sort of thing.

Comment: Dear @463035818_is_not_a_number. As you said, I can have two times calling  the edit function instead of having two function that one change the int parameter and other change int and float for instance. But I was thinking that it would be easier for the user of these class to use one time the edit parameter and just provide the parameters he wants to change.

Comment: And upvoted for having the instinct that there's a better way. That's a hallmark of a good programmer. You can't teach that.

Comment: Related to [how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads).

Answer (score 7):

With variadic and (ab)using `std::get<T>` on `std::tuple`, you might do

```
template <typename... Ts>
void edit(Ts... values)
{
    ((std::get<Ts&>(std::tie(a, b, c)) = std::get<Ts&>(std::tie(values...))), ...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6G6fW174K).

Note: I use `std::get<Ts&>(std::tie(values...))` instead of simply `values` to get error with duplicated input types(`edit(42, 42);`).

Comment: Why am I the only upvoter? This is the most elegant answer so far this week.

Comment: @Bathsheba: with the beginning of the new Chinese year, I might even hope for this year ;-)

Comment: is there some calender that just stared a new millenia ? :P

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the huge number of overloads and still allow the caller to set more than one member in a single expression:

```
class foo
  {
  public:
      foo(int _a, char _b, float _c) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c){};
      foo& edit(int new_a) { a = new_a; return *this;}
      foo& edit(char new_b) { b = new_b; return *this; }
      foo& edit(float new_c) { c = new_c; return *this; }
      
  private:
     int   a;
     char  b;
     float c;
};

int main() {
    foo f(1,'c',2.0);
    f.edit(42).edit(42.0f).edit('a');
}
```

Adding a member requires you to write one overload rather than `N` to support all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Given your `edit` functions that modify a single member:

```
void edit(int new_a)
{
    a = new_a;
}
void edit(char new_b)
{
    b = new_b;
}
void edit(float new_c)
{
    c = new_c;
}
```

You can define a single function in **C++11** using [variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634379/variadic-templates) to support multiple parameters in terms of multiple calls with a single parameter:

```
template< typename FirstType, typename ...OtherTypes >
void edit(FirstType ft, OtherTypes ...ot)
{
    edit(ft);
    edit(ot...);
}
```

Using **C++17**, [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) can make this function even simpler.

```
template< typename ...Types >
void edit(Types ...types)
{
    (edit(types), ...);
}
```

Note:  This solution will not try to prevent multiple changes to the same type, such as `edit(1, 2, 3);`

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions are quite fine, but suppose that all elements have a different type.

A possibility is to still use a variadic template, and in the call to indicate with a `string` which element must be modified.
This would allow the possibility to have the same type for different elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class foo {
  public:
      foo(int _a, char _b, float _c) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c){};
      void edit() {};
      template<typename T1, typename... T2>
      void edit (const std::string& id, T1 var1, T2... var2) {
          if (id == "a") a = var1;
          else if (id == "b") b = var1;
          else if (id == "c") c = var1;
          edit(var2...);
      };
      void info();
  //private:
     int   a;
     char  b;
     float c;
};

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& obj) {
    std::cout << "a = " << obj.a <<  " b = " << obj.b << " c = " << obj.c;
    return os;
  }

int main() {
    foo example(1, 'a', 2.0);
    example.edit("c", 3.0f, "b", 'g', "a", 5);
    std::cout << example << std::endl;
}
```